# Joomla 3.0 JFactory::getApplication() get always returns null

Tags: php, arrays, joomla3.0

I'm trying the extract the array data from a nested array (shown is part of a var_dump):

```
["passcodes"]=> array(2) { 
    [0]=> array(1) { 
            [0]=> string(33) "pAWn78hI2Uw5FA9iSGVuAkvISM0LTWL9X" 
        } 
    [1]=> array(1) { 
            [0]=> string(33) "dfS7VHqEXmcSkBubESaA0mIt8rEy2fSWE" 
        } 
}
```

With the following PHP:

```
<?php
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$input = $app->input;

$codes= $input->get('passcodes',array(),'array');

echo "*********** ".$codes." **********";
print_r($codes);
var_dump($codes);
var_dump($input);
?>
```

^^ I can't seem how to figure out the declaration for $codes, it's always null and size 0

Comment: Where is that array (the one you've posted at top) coming from?

Comment: Fabrik Form, this from onbeforeprocess; I need to manipulate the data before it's stored

Comment: Ok, but how were you able to get that array? You var dumped from where?

Comment: I am using the Joomla! component Fabrik.  I have a form where the user enters/selects.  When the users submits the form everything is saved into MYSQL tables. This works no issues.  Fabrik allows me to run a script on the form data before it's saved to MYSQL.  It calls my custom PHP script.  For example I can get the username with  JFactory::getUser(), I can get form items with "$input->get('user_entered_item','','string');" --- But this Array in the (dump) is eluding me.

Comment: The array itself in the code quote above I get from: "var_dump($input);"  The form itself has many items on it, so I quoted one part of the var_dump to make the question shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$input->get('passcodes',array(),'array')` try:

```
$vars   = 'passcodes'; // Associative array of keys and filter types to apply
$source = 'youArrayName'; // Array to retrieve data from 
$codes  = $input->getArray(array $vars, $source);
```